# SaveAs file name with new format in current folder

Tags: vba, ms-word, filepath, save-as

I have setup the following macro in a Word Template to save my file to the place where the template is current saved, but in a sub-folder with a new name and file format.  Each time I run the macro I get a "Command failed" Error.

Here is my code:

```
pathName = ActiveDocument.Path & "\Periodic Count\CaseManager_CSV.txt"
ActiveDocument.SaveAs fileName:=pathName, FileFormat:=wdFormatText
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason of your problem stem from unsaved document which doesn't have a path. As a result your `pathName variable` value is only like this: `"\Periodic Count\CaseManager_CSV.txt"` which is incorrect.

As you mentioned you want to save in the subfolder of the folder where your template is saved. Possibly you should modify `pathName variable` in this way:

```
pathName = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.Path & "\Periodic Count\CaseManager_CSV.txt"
```